# Comparison between InputField text and the answer text doesn't work properly; Unity3d; C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I am trying to make a game where the player is controlled by an input field. When I try to store the value or the written text from the input field in a String and the compare the string to the solution string, it doesn't work. I have tried to work with debug.log functions everywhere to see when the code stops working, but I still can't see what the problem is. I have been looking for YouTube videos, unity-& other game development forums, but none of the proposed solutions seem to work with my code. I am fairly new to game development, and so maybe the solution is easy.

Here is the code i used but doesn't work as expected:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InputFieldComparision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField inputFieldInMainUi;
    private string Txt; 

void Update()
    {
        Txt = inputFieldInMainUi.text.ToUpper();
        Debug.Log(Txt);

        #region comparison

        if (Txt == "MR")
        {
            Debug.Log("Move Right");
        }

        else if (Txt == "MM")
        {
            Debug.Log("move middle");
        }

        else if (Txt == "ML")
        {
            Debug.Log("move left");
        }

        else if (Txt == "J")
        {
            Debug.Log("jump");
        }

        else if (Txt == "M")
        {
            Debug.Log("menu");
        }

        else if (Txt == "Q")
        {
            Debug.Log("quit");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I think the code doesn't store the value of the Input field in the String properly and therefore can't be compared.

Comment: Just to make sure: Is the reference for the input field set correctly in the inspector? Do you actually get the input field's string at any point in time? In other words, is the comparison not working or is there no string available at all. By briefly looking at your code, it should work, if the string is provided. In another matter. It would probably make sense to compare only if the input field's content changed. You can assign a callback for that under the ```InputField``` section of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the == operator is used to compare the reference identity. The Equals() method compares the content.

Change your code using Equals() method like:

```
if (Txt.Equals("MR"))
{
    Debug.Log("Move Right");
}
```

Make sure to bind/link the variable inputFieldInMainUi to the input field in your UI. I'm not familiar with Unity3D, but there should be an option to link the variable inputFieldInMainUi to the actual field.

Lastly try debugging and put a breakpoint at the line where you assign a value to Txt, make sure this variable contains the string-value that you want to compare to

```
Txt = inputFieldInMainUi.text.ToUpper();
```

Comment: I replaced the "==" with the ".Equals()" method and added the debug-breakpoint and ran the game a couple of times, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything... do you have any other ideas I could try?

Comment: Did your code enter stop at the breakpoint (when debugging)?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happened

Comment: I think you have to bind/link the variable inputFieldInMainUi to the input field in your UI. I'm not familiar to Unity3D, but there should be an option to link the variable inputFieldInMainUi to the actual field.

Comment: I think this article will be usefull for solving your issue: https://forum.unity.com/threads/can-someone-explain-binding-to-me-in-the-context-of-ui-toolkit.855142/

Comment: I honestly don't know how I could have forgotten to check such an easy mistake... but you're 100% right I didn't link the Input field, but I just tried to do so and I can't select my Input field, and I am also not able to drag it in. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Please refer to my earlier comment above:) Make sure you are actually using an ```InputField```. Maybe you are using ```TMPro``` input field, then you need to adjust the type reference in your script to ```TMP_InputField```. Let me know if you need any further help. Not able to referene an object means that the reference types are not the same.

Comment: Put this  [SerializeField] before the declaration public InputField inputFieldInMainUi; 
@anjelomerte most likely he's using TMPro

Comment: @Tassisto Could be;) Let's see. Off personal interest, is it actually necessary to put ```[SerializeField]``` up front?

Comment: The declaration of inputfield should change to 

[SerializeField]
public TMP_InputField inputFieldInMainUi;

Comment: `First of all the == operator` only checks for reference equality as a default behavior in case the according type doesn't implement and overwrite that operator .. which [`string` does](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#string-equality) .. you might still want to use `Equals` in order to further [specify equality parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings) auch as ignoring case etc

Comment: @Tassisto `[SerializeField] public` is redundant. `public` is enough. [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) is for **additionally** serialize **non-public** fields `When Unity serializes your scripts, it only serializes public fields. If you also want Unity to serialize your private fields you can add the SerializeField attribute to those fields.`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to everybody who tried to help me with my problem, I was now finally able to find a solution. If you are interested in what was the problem I try to describe it to you: At the top of every unity-C# scrip we find the using tags, I didn't know you had to use a special using TMPro tag and therefore wasn't able to define my Inputfield as TMP_Inputfield. I once again what to thank you for your time and support :)